# Preventing "boldification" of glossary items

Tags: math-mode, glossaries

Is there a way to ***prevent***  **"boldification"** of the glossary entry names and symbols in the **Glossary** chapter?

I have managed to produce `newglossarystyle` similar to `altlist` based on `list` that includes the `symbol` property in the `glossaryentryfield`.

However, some of my entries have `symbol` and `name` formatted in plain text (e.g. `"Ss"`) but other entries include *math* (e.g. `"\ensuremath{N_s}"`).

In the main text the above are nicely displayed, however the in the **Glossary** chapter plain text entries are getting **bold**, but math aren't. This looks inconsistent and ugly.

Is there a way to ***prevent*** this **"boldification"** of the glossary entry names and symbols in the **Glossary** chapter?

```
\makeatletter
\newglossarystyle{altlistSymbol}{%
    \glossarystyle{list}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
        \item[\glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{##4}]%
        \mbox{}\newline%\mbox{}\par\nobreak\@afterheading%
        {##2}%
        \mbox{}\newline%\mbox{}\par\nobreak\@afterheading%
        {##3}\glspostdescription\space {##5}}%
    \renewcommand{\glossarysubentryfield}[6]{%
        \par
        \glssubentryitem{##2}%
        \glstarget{##2}{\strut}##4\glspostdescription\space {##6}}%
}
\makeatother
```

Moving the `\glstarget{##1}{##4}` outside the `item[...]` seems to be a *dirty trick* and it changes the left-positioning of the text.

```
\item[\glsentryitem{##1}]\glstarget{##1}{##4}%
```

Also, changing all of may entries to mathmode is unfeasible.

MWE:

```
% arara: xelatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: xelatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: xelatex
% arara: xelatex

\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\newglossary[slg]{symbols}{sym}{sbl}{Symbols}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{number}{
type            = {symbols},
name            = {number, glossary entry name},
symbol          = {\ensuremath{N_s}},
sort            = {n},
description     = {number, glossary entry description}
}

\newglossaryentry{subject}{
type            = {symbols},
name            = {subject},
plural          = {subjects},
symbol          = {S},
symbolplural    = {Ss},
sort            = {s},
description     = {plural \glsentrysymbolplural{subject}, glossary entry description}
}   

\makeatletter
\newglossarystyle{altlistSymbol}{%
    \glossarystyle{list}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
        \item[\glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{##4}]%
        \mbox{}\newline%\mbox{}\par\nobreak\@afterheading%
        {##2}%
        \mbox{}\newline%\mbox{}\par\nobreak\@afterheading%
        {##3}\glspostdescription\space {##5}}%
    \renewcommand{\glossarysubentryfield}[6]{%
        \par
        \glssubentryitem{##2}%
        \glstarget{##2}{\strut}##4\glspostdescription\space {##6}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\null
\glsaddall

\printglossary[type=symbols,style=altlistSymbol]

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's probably a `{description}` list so you could try and add a redefinition of `\descriptionlabel` to the definition of the glossary style: `\renewcommand*\descriptionlabel[1]{\hspace\labelsep\normalfont#1}` (this is the standard definition but without `\bfseries`)

Comment: @cgnieder Works like charm! - thankin you a lot!

Comment: Just redefine `\glsnamefont` as described in [the glossaries FAQ](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/faqs/glossariesfaq.html#whybold)

Comment: @nicola-talbot : yup, but this takes effect on <code>name</code> only and if a symbol is contained in the <code>item</code> as in my example (<code>glstarget{##1}{##4}</code>), then unfortunately it will still be in __bold__

So far I have found using:
    \renewcommand*\descriptionlabel[1]{\hspace\labelsep\normalfont #1}
    \printglossaries
    \renewcommand*\descriptionlabel[1]{\hspace\labelsep\normalfont\bfseries #1}

(as proposed by @cgnieder) working quite fine.

But, the hint with <code>\glsnamefont</code> is still very useful, handy, insightful and "general understanding broadening"

Comment: @NeuroTeX Sorry, I didn't notice you also had the symbol in the item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `list` glossary style uses `description`; you can modify it by resetting the environment with `enumitem`:

```
% arara: xelatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: xelatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: xelatex
% arara: xelatex

\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\newglossary[slg]{symbols}{sym}{sbl}{Symbols}
\makeglossaries

\show\glsgroupheading

\newglossaryentry{number}{
type            = {symbols},
name            = {number, glossary entry name},
symbol          = {\ensuremath{N_s}},
sort            = {n},
description     = {number, glossary entry description}
}

\newglossaryentry{subject}{
type            = {symbols},
name            = {subject},
plural          = {subjects},
symbol          = {S},
symbolplural    = {Ss},
sort            = {s},
description     = {plural \glsentrysymbolplural{subject}, glossary entry description}
}   

\makeatletter
\newglossarystyle{altlistSymbol}{%
    \glossarystyle{list}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
        \item[\glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{##4}]%
        \mbox{}\newline%\mbox{}\par\nobreak\@afterheading%
        {##2}%
        \mbox{}\newline%\mbox{}\par\nobreak\@afterheading%
        {##3}\glspostdescription\space {##5}}%
    \renewcommand{\glossarysubentryfield}[6]{%
        \par
        \glssubentryitem{##2}%
        \glstarget{##2}{\strut}##4\glspostdescription\space {##6}}%
\renewenvironment{theglossary}
 {\begin{description}[font=\normalfont]}
 {\end{description}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\null
\glsaddall

\printglossary[type=symbols,style=altlistSymbol]

\end{document}
```

[image]